# How to notate a function that's restricted to L² (or any space) in only some of its arguments?

Tags: functions, notation, lp-spaces

What's the proper notation to indicate that a function is restricted to a particular space in only *some* of its arguments?

For example, in non-relativistic quantum mechanics for one particle in the position space, the wave function is written $\psi(t,\vec{x})$ and solves $i\hbar\partial_t\psi(t,\vec{x})=\hat{H}\psi(t,\vec{x})$.

This function is $\psi:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{C}$, but it has additional restrictions.  For any constant $t$, $\psi(\vec{x})$ for $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{C}$ lies in $L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$ (with $L^2(X)$ [on measure space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html) $X$).  How can this restriction be shown when expressing the domain & codomain in arrow notation?

Possibly $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{C})$ or $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to L^2_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R}^3)$?  But I've never seen any notation that indicates whether $^2(Σ)$ is over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and [different answers disagree about which is intended unless specified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335450/meaning-of-the-notation-l2-mathbbr3-and-its-generalization).  How can this be notated?

(Ignore other properties of this example, e.g. $L^2$ equivalence class, projective space, C* details).

Comment: I know the notation $$\|f\|_{(p,q)}:=\left(\int_{\Bbb R^m}\left[\int_{\Bbb R^n}|f(x,y)|^q dy\right]^{p/q}dx\right)^{1/p}$$ for $f:\Bbb R^{m+n}\to E$. And $\mathcal L_{p,q}(\Bbb R^{m+n},R):=\{f\in E^{\Bbb R^{m+n}}:\|f\|_{(p,q)}<\infty\}$. Maybe you can fit this notation for your case. This notation is useful for the [integral Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski's_integral_inequality).

Comment: then $\|{\cdot}\|_{(p,q)}$ is a seminorm in $\mathcal L_{(p,q)}$, thus we can define $L_{(p,q)}:=\mathcal L_{(p,q)}/\mathcal N$ as the quotient space where $\mathcal N=\{f\in\mathcal L_{(p,q)}: f=0\text{ a.e. }\}$, then $\|{\cdot}\|_{(p,q)}$ is a norm in $L_{(p,q)}$.

Comment: in the general case you can use the notation $f\in L_{(0,2)}(\Bbb R^{m+n},\Bbb C)$, what could be understood as saying that $f$ is measurable and that $\int_{\Bbb R^n}|f(x,y)|^2\, dy <\infty$ for any chosen $x$, in analogy to the previous notation together with the common notation $f\in L_0$ meaning that $f$ is a measurable function.

Comment: @Masacroso Your notation worked perfectly.  If you stick it in an answer, I can accept it.